# Put two 100% width divs side-by-side

Tags: javascript, html, css

So if I want to have two divs, each of 100% of the entire page, side by side, given that the wrapper has `overflow:hidden`, how should I go about implementing it?

I have tried using `inline-block` but it did not work.

I have tried using `float` **too** but it caused errors.

I want the second div to be hidden so I can change it's left as an animation, sort of like a slide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want your page to have a width of 200%?

Comment: Either remove the `overflow:hidden` from the wrapper, or make sure it has a width of 200%.

Comment: Is that so? I want the second div to be hidden so I can change it's `left` as an animation, sort of like a slide.

Comment: @ihsoyih You should put that in the question, as it isn't in there now.

Comment: @ihsoyih if you are doing it with animation then you don't really need to try to figure it out with css. Your javascript could get the width of the container, set it to the new hidden div right before moving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be purely a matter of positioning one of the divs off the page using absolute positioning and transitioning the left property using either hover state or javascript.

Hover the red div.

**[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dzKFt)**

Comment: Thanks to Olly too, but this one had a better example. Thanks to both of you anyway!

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry to disturb you again, but is there a way to make the contents relative instead of absolute? Right now the entire container collapses.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood you correctly, you can achieve what you're after using `inline-block`. You just have to be a little careful with white space (i.e. you need to make sure you've got no white space between the two child `div` elements). I've stopped the `div`s from wrapping by setting `white-space: nowrap;`.

```
<div class="foo">
    <div> woo woo !</div><div> woo woo !</div>
</div>

.foo {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;        
}
    .foo > div {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 100%;
        background: aqua;
    }
    .foo > div +  div {
        background: lime;
    }
```

Try it out at http://jsfiddle.net/8Q3pS/2/.

**Edit:** Here's an alternative implementation using `position: absolute;`: http://jsfiddle.net/8Q3pS/5/. That way you'll be able to animate the second one into view using `left`. Note that you'll need to set a height on the parent `div`.

```
.foo {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    .foo > div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: aqua;
    }
    .foo > div +  div {
        left: 100%;
        background: lime;
    }
```

Comment: Does the container need to be `position:relative`?

Comment: Not in the first example - I'll edit. For the second example, the container needs to be positioned, so that the child elements are positioned relative to it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not set max-width to 100%, not set the actual width and float them side by side?  With both overflow:hidden, as they expand it should create horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: This is asking what the OP wants, and as such is better suited for a comment than an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I don't want scrollbars, it should be completely hidden from view.

Comment: You are correct that should be a comment and didn't realize it until after I had submitted it.